# Can I draw flow chart in MarkDown with in page link?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, flowchart, mermaid

I'm on Windows 10, editing MarkDown files with VS-Code.

I would like to draw a flow chart like graph and adding in page links to nodes in the graph.

I read through the documentation of both [mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/README) and [flowchat.js](https://flowchart.js.org/), they only provide the net link method.

What I am looking for is an in page jump after the click, lead the readers to the place where the detail explanation of the node is located in the file.

Would there be a way to create that kind of graph? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation [Interaction](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=interaction) this can be done with `click`:

> It is possible to bind a click event to a node, the click can lead to
>   either a javascript callback or to a link which will be opened in a
>   new browser tab.
>
> Examples of tooltip usage below:
>
> ```
> <script>
>     var callback = function(){
>         alert('A callback was triggered');
>     }
> <script>
> graph LR;
>     A-->B;
>     click A callback "Tooltip for a callback"
>     click B "http://www.github.com" "This is a tooltip for a link"
> ```

To get an in page link you can use the `#` in the link. I put together the following example:

````
```mermaid
graph LR;
    A-->B;
    click B ".#test" "Tooltip..."
```

(some text...)

## Test
````

Comment: really sorry for the late reply. I tried this but vscode report an error of "cannot find file .#test" in the preview. BTW, I'm in windows platform...

Comment: Sorry, you wrote that you are editing in VS Code. What plugin do you use for the preview? Perhaps the plugin does not handle it correctly...

Comment: Hi @BiNZGi I tried both default preview with "markdown preview mermaid support" and the "markdown preview enhanced". Both does not support. I prefer to use markdown preview enhanced, since it produce PDF. Thanks a lot and sorry again for the late reply.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I tried with both and it seems not to work :-( It seems that not all rendering engines do this the same way. I tried it with gitlab and made a copy over here: https://gitlab.com/BiNZGi/markdown/tree/59371468/